# What tools can I use to create a single PNG from multiple images?

Tags: java

I have a lot of small images like [image: this orange box] that I want to compose into a PNG file (for CSS sprites) like [image: this orange box with a magnifying glass and shopping cart next to it]. I'm using Photoshop to do this, but I think there should be a tool to compose images—even better, to give me every image's position in pixels.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mean something like [this](http://spritegen.website-performance.org/) for css sprite?

Answer (score 1):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/) or one of its many bindings.